# Sharply t-transitive groups.

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

Suppose that $G$ acts sharply $t$-transitively on a set $\{1,\cdots, n\}$. Then I want to show that if $n = t + 2$ then $G = A_n$.

I can indeed show this, but I feel it's unnecessarily messy. My way involves showing that $G$ must contain double transpositions, but never single ones.

It would be nice to see a nice snappy argument though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The conditions completely determine the order of the group to be $\frac{n!}{2!}$ (see for example my answer to [Degree of a permutation group](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/314067/degree-of-a-permutation-group/)), so we know it will be a subgroup of $S_n$ of index $2$. The only such subgroup is $A_n$.

Comment: Of course, so simple.

Comment: Simple but leading +